# Oracle APEX - Password checker

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to create a password checker. I need to implement something like this:
[image]

I've been looking for how to implement a password checker like the example above but haven't been able to find it.
I added a region in between the new password field and confirm password field to add the password validation:
[image]

Is there anyone who knows how to do this in oracle apex?
The first screenshot is from w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_password_validation.asp)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create **validation** on password item and compose resulting string, displaying only what's wrong with it (validation would be a *function returning error text*).

If you want it to look like screenshot you posted, then you could create a **classic report** whose source is union of several `SELECT` statements, each of them returning one row (validation) and its outcome. This is a SQL*Plus example, but query would remain the same:

```
SQL> var p1_password varchar2(20)
SQL> exec :p1_password := 'Littlefoot';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

This is sample code; you can copy/paste it into report's source and it should work:

```
SQL> with temp (pwd) as
  2    (select :P1_PASSWORD from dual)
  3  select
  4    'A lowercase letter' text,
  5    case when regexp_like(pwd, '[a-z]') then 'OK'
  6         else 'NOK'
  7    end result
  8  from temp
  9  union all
 10  select
 11    'A capital (uppercase) letter',
 12    case when regexp_like(pwd, '[A-Z]') then 'OK'
 13         else 'NOK'
 14    end
 15  from temp
 16  union all
 17  select
 18    'A number',
 19    case when regexp_like(pwd, '[0-9]') then 'OK'
 20         else 'NOK'
 21    end
 22  from temp
 23  union all
 24  select 'Minimum 8 characters',
 25    case when length(pwd) >= 8 then 'OK'
 26         else 'NOK'
 27    end
 28  from temp;
```

Result:

```
TEXT                         RES
---------------------------- ---
A lowercase letter           OK
A capital (uppercase) letter OK
A number                     NOK
Minimum 8 characters         OK

SQL>
```

Now that it works, it is matter of making it pretty (include colors, check marks, whatever you want).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd like to make this field dynamic. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: What does it mean (to make this field "dynamic")? Dynamic in what way?

Comment: I mean, when the user enter the password, it returns "valid" or "invalid" right away

Comment: If it's implemented as a classic report, you can refresh it within a dynamic action whenever you choose

Comment: Also FYI, there's a password complexity checker in the db (ora_complexity_check) https://seanstuber.com/2021/04/20/ora_complexity_check-quirks-and-alternative/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is the complete steps and codes.

1. Put this JS function in page's JavaScript > Function and Global Variable Declaration

```js
function showPasswordError() {
    var newpasswd = $('#P10009_NEW_PASSWORD').val();
    var string = '';
    // check null    
    if ($('#P10009_CHECK_CURRENT_PASSWORD').val() !== '' && ($('#P10009_NEW_PASSWORD').val() !== '' && $('#P10009_CONFIRM_PASSWORD').val() !== '')) {
        // check current password
        if ($('#P10009_CHECK_CURRENT_PASSWORD').val() === $('#P10009_CURRENT_PASSWORD').val()) {
            // check new password & confirm password are the same
            if ($('#P10009_NEW_PASSWORD').val() === $('#P10009_CONFIRM_PASSWORD').val()) {
                // check new password length
                if (newpasswd.length < 8) {
                    string += '<p style="color:red;"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times"></span> Minimun 8 characters</p>';
                }
                else {
                    string += '<p style="color:green;"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check"></span> Minimun 8 characters</p>';
                }
                
                // check lowercase letter
                if (newpasswd.search(/[a-z]/i) < 0) {
                    string += '<p style="color:red;"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times"></span> A lowercase letter</p>';
                }
                else {
                    string += '<p style="color:green;"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check"></span> A lowercase letter</p>';
                }
                
                // check digit
                if (newpasswd.search(/[0-9]/) < 0) {
                    string += '<p style="color:red;"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times"></span> A number</p>';
                }
                else {
                    string += '<p style="color:green;"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check"></span> A number</p>';
                }
                
                // check uppercase letter
                if (newpasswd.search(/[A-Z]/) < 0) {
                    string += '<p style="color:red;"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times"></span> A capital(uppercase) letter</p>';
                }
                else {
                    string += '<p style="color:green;"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check"></span> A capital(uppercase) letter</p>';
                }

                $('#PASSWORD_ERROR').html(string);
            } else {
                $('#PASSWORD_ERROR').html('<span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times"></span> Your confirm password is not the same!');
            }
        } else {
            $('#PASSWORD_ERROR').html('<span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times"></span> Wrong current password!');
        }
    } else {
        $('#PASSWORD_ERROR').html('<span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times"></span> Please enter all password fields.');
    }
}
```

2. add DA of "Key Release" on all 3 input fields and call this js function "showPasswordError()", and set to Fire on initialization - Yes
3. Create a region to show error and put this html inside the region.

   `<div id="PASSWORD_ERROR" style="color:red;"></div>`

You should have a hidden field to save current password.

Now, whenever you type anything in these 3 fields, the js function should be  called and check and show the errors.

*New and Confirm password fields are using just text type to show you a sample.